# Parse many values from one column --> ERROR:The Maximum Possible Row Length in the Table is too Large

Tags: regex, parsing, sas, teradata

I want to parse a lot information from a column into several columns. My code looks like this:

```
%let Temp_pattern = 'GPU = (\d*)\s(\d*)\s(\d*)\s(\d*)\s(\d*)\s(\d*)\s(\d*)\s(\d*)\s\sHDD = (\d*)\s(\d*)\s(\d*)\s(\d*)\s(\d*)\s(\d*)\s(\d*)\s(\d*)\s(\d*)\s(\d*)\s(\d*)\s(\d*)';

proc sql;
    connect to teradata as tdconn ( DBSLICEPARM=(THREADED_APPS,4) SERVER=BASDW authdomain=TeradataAuthPRD  );
    execute      
    (
   CREATE TABLE TERADATA_TABLE.WANT 
    (   event_timestamp 
        ,id1 
        ,id2 
        ,date       
        ,source
        ,id
/*      ,text*/
        ,GPU_TEMP_1 
        /*and 20 more columns*/
        )
    AS (
        SELECT event_timestamp
        ,id1 
        ,id2 
        ,date       
        ,source
        ,id
/*      ,text*/
        ,case CHARACTER_LENGTH(regexp_replace(text,&Temp_pattern .,'\1')) when  CHARACTER_LENGTH(event_text) then NULL else regexp_replace(text,&Temp_pattern .,'\1') end as GPU_TEMP_1 
        /*and 20 more columns*/

        from TERADATA_TABLE2.HAVE
        where   date = '2018-02-18'     
                and source = 'AAA' 
                and id = 8
                and text like 'Temperature%'
    ) WITH DATA;
    ) by tdconn;
    execute (commit work) by tdconn;
    disconnect from tdconn;
quit;
run;
```

And because I want to create so many columns i get the ERROR Message:

> ERROR: Teradata execute: The Maximum Possible Row Length in the Table is too Large.

How to prevent that? I know that there are quite big Tables out there in Teradata so why is it not possible to create one like that? I know there is a row-limit by 64k but i wannt to go around that. 
Do I have to iterate and add one column each time? And how can I do that?

Comment: `REGEXP_REPLACE` returns a huge Varchar (probably VarChar(8000)), when you add multiple you hit the limit. Simply CAST the results to a shorter varchars.

Comment: thank you that worked --> `,cast(case CHARACTER_LENGTH(regexp_replace(text,&Temp_pattern .,'\1')) when  CHARACTER_LENGTH(text) then NULL else regexp_replace(text,&Temp_pattern .,'\1') end as INTEGER)  as GPU_TEMP_1`